# Como filtrar registros por data usando SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou usando o SQL Server e preciso consultar em uma tabela o registro mais recente de preço conforme a data. De todos os registros, preciso que ele me traga apenas 1 e com a data atual. Como faço isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua coluna é varchar? O resultado que vc espera é a data 12/03/2018?

Comment: Tente algo assim man: <b>select top 1 vr_preco from tabela where dt_data = (select max(dt_data) from tabela)</b>. Obs: estou considerando que o campo dt_data é date.

Comment: Qual é a versão do SQL Server?

Comment: Versão 2017....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Será algo como isto que procura?

```
SELECT      TOP 1 *
FROM        Tabela
ORDER BY    DT_DATA DESC
```

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição @João Martins :)

Comment: De nada, sempre às ordens! Se a resposta foi útil, pf dê um UP :)

Answer (score 3):

Pela figura percebe-se que há várias linhas para um mesmo produto.

A solução varia de acordo com a versão do SQL Server. Considerando-se obter informações mais recentes de um único produto, podemos ter:

```
-- código #2
with Produto_ord as (
    SELECT ID_PRODUTOEMPRESA, DT_DATA, VR_PRECO,
           seq= row_number() over (order by DT_DATA desc)
      from tabela
      where ID_PRODUTOEMPRESA = ___
)
SELECT ID_PRODUTOEMPRESA, DT_DATA, VR_PRECO
  from Produto_ord
  where seq = 1;
```

Comment: Obrigado @José Diz